# Which browsers support multiple keyword values for the CSS display property?

Tags: css

[CSS3 allows](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties) specifying display-outside and display-inside values within a single `display` rule.

For example:

```
display: block flow;
display: inline table;
display: flex run-in;
```

The [CSS MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) doesn't say which browsers support this multi-keyword syntax.

Which browsers currently support CSS3's multiple keyword values for `display`, and what quirks are present (if any) among those that do support it?

---

EDIT (response to close votes):

I'm *not* asking for a recommendation or for someone to find an outside tool/resource.

The question's intent is to help me (and others) decide whether or not to use this CSS feature in code I write, based on how well-supported it is in current target platforms (browser engines), NOT to help me choose a browser (I already have all of them -- IE, Edge, Chrome, FF, Safari, and I develop and test against the most recent versions of all of them).

Basically, I'm asking the same question [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) answers for [flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), but for a different CSS feature. I.e. *What would the impact on my user base be if I were to use this CSS feature?* (which depends on my app’s user base, but which anyone can answer for themselves given data on browser support for hr feature in question)

There are many examples of this type of question already on SO (I can provide in comments/discussion if interested).

Comment: Since no browser supports the [`display-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-inside) nor the [`display-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-outside) which are the expanded versions of `display`, no browser supports multiple values for the short version.

Comment: @RoyTinker in fact the whole **Display Module** (*which added the multi-keyword values*) is not supported by any browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Display)

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: Implementations not supporting the longhands has nothing to do with them not supporting the updated syntax. The longhands were simply *replaced* with the updated syntax in the draft several years ago (there's a reason the longhands were not implemented to begin with). And css-display-3 *is* partially implemented in some browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no implementations of the multi-value version of `display` as currently defined in css-display-3.

The only features new to css-display-3 that are implemented (not including features defined in their own CSS modules, such as flex layout, grid layout and ruby layout) are `display: contents` and `display: flow-root`, but these are implemented as single keyword values, which means implementations do not currently recognize `display: block flow-root` despite recognizing `display: flow-root`.

Considering that css-display-3 is still undergoing major clarifications and even rewrites as of 2017, I wouldn't hold my breath on implementations anytime soon, especially since the current definition of `display` requires reimplementing the property altogether (namely, moving from single-value to multi-value while ensuring that existing values and legacy values continue to work as intended and don't break for existing sites), not to mention perhaps an overhaul of the CSS layout system depending on how it's currently being implemented, warts and all.